# Rails – Nested Resource - My edit and delete methods retrieve the wrong IDs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form, nested-resources

Thank you for taking the time to review this question.

I have a nested resource called templates, which belong to categories. I have the template create, edit and delete actions displayed in the Category Show page. I am able to create with no issue, however, when attempting to edit or delete the same template gets retrieved by its ID (usually the first template created under a category).

**Code**

config/routes.rb

```
  resources :categories do
    resources :templates
```

app/models/template.rb

```
class Template < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :category
  validates :title, presence: true
  validates :content, presence: true
end
```

app/models/category.rb

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :templates, dependent: :destroy
  validates :name, presence: true
end
```

db/schema.rb

```
create_table "categories", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_categories_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "templates", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.integer "category_id"
    t.string "title"
    t.text "content"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["category_id"], name: "index_templates_on_category_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_templates_on_user_id"
  end
```

app/views/categories/show.html.erb

```
  <% @templates.each do |template| %>
    <div class= "template-grid">
      <div class= "template-index-card">
        <h1><%= template.title%></h1>
        <p><%= template.content %></p>
        <div class= "template-options">
          <%= link_to image_tag("edit.png", class: "icon"), edit_category_template_path([@category, @template])%>
          <%= link_to image_tag("bin.png", class: "icon"), category_template_path([@category, @template]), method: :delete,
            data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }%>
```

app/views/templates/edit.html.erb

```
<%= simple_form_for([@category, @template]) do |f| %>
  <div class="form-inputs">
      <%= f.input :title %>
      <%= f.input :content %>
  </div>
  <div class= "form-btn-flex">
      <%= f.button :submit, "Update Template", class:"btn-mdpm-forms"%>
    <% end %>
```

app/controllers/templates_controller.rb

```
class TemplatesController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @template = Template.new
  end

  def create
    @template = Template.new(template_params)
    @template.user_id = current_user.id
    @template.category = Category.find(params[:category_id])
    if @template.save
      redirect_to category_path(@template.category_id)
    else
      render :show
    end
  end

  def index
    @templates = Template.all
  end

  def show
    @template = Template.find(params[:id])
  end

  def edit
    @category = Category.find(params[:category_id])
    @template = @category.templates.find_by(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @category = Category.find_by(params[:category_id])
    @template = @category.templates.find_by(params[:id])
    if @template.update(template_params)
      redirect_to category_path(@category)
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @template = Template.find_by(params[:id])
    @template.destroy
    redirect_to category_path(@template.category_id)
  end

  private

  def template_params
    params.require(:template).permit(:title, :content)
  end
end
```

app/controllers/categories_controller.rb

```
class CategoriesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_category, only: [:edit, :update]

  def new
    @category = Category.new
  end

  def create
    @category = Category.new(category_params)
    @category.user = current_user
    if @category.save
      redirect_to categories_path
    else
      render :index
    end
  end

  def index
    @category = Category.new
    @categories = Category.all
  end

  def show
    @template = Template.new
    @category = Category.find(params[:id])
    @templates = @category.templates
  end

  def edit
    @category = Category.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    if @category.update(category_params)
      redirect_to category_path(@category)
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @category = Category.find(params[:id])
    @category.destroy
    redirect_to categories_path
  end

  private

  def category_params
    params.require(:category).permit(:name)
  end

  def set_category
    @category = Category.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

Routes

```
      category_templates GET    /categories/:category_id/templates(.:format)                                             templates#index
                          POST   /categories/:category_id/templates(.:format)                                             templates#create
    new_category_template GET    /categories/:category_id/templates/new(.:format)                                         templates#new
   edit_category_template GET    /categories/:category_id/templates/:id/edit(.:format)                                    templates#edit
        category_template GET    /categories/:category_id/templates/:id(.:format)                                         templates#show
                          PATCH  /categories/:category_id/templates/:id(.:format)                                         templates#update
                          PUT    /categories/:category_id/templates/:id(.:format)                                         templates#update
                          DELETE /categories/:category_id/templates/:id(.:format)                                         templates#destroy
               categories GET    /categories(.:format)                                                                    categories#index
                          POST   /categories(.:format)                                                                    categories#create
             new_category GET    /categories/new(.:format)                                                                categories#new
            edit_category GET    /categories/:id/edit(.:format)                                                           categories#edit
                 category GET    /categories/:id(.:format)                                                                categories#show
                          PATCH  /categories/:id(.:format)                                                                categories#update
                          PUT    /categories/:id(.:format)                                                                categories#update
                          DELETE /categories/:id(.:format)                                                                categories#destroy
```

Thanks!

Comment: Since the link is in categories/show view, show us categories_controller

Comment: I've added the categories_controlles. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem ended up being a matter of too many variables named the same. In order to fix the issue I had to make the following changes:

1 - On app/views/categories/show.html.erb I removed the @ form template since I was inside an iteration, I also passed the params not as an array as suggested.

```
  <% @templates.each do |template| %>
    <div class= "template-grid">
      <div class= "template-index-card">
        <h1><%= template.title%></h1>
        <p><%= template.content %></p>
        <div class= "template-options">
          <%= link_to image_tag("edit.png", class: "icon"), edit_category_template_path(@category, template)%>
          <%= link_to image_tag("bin.png", class: "icon"), category_template_path(@category, template), method: :delete,
            data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }%>
```

2. I updated the name of the @template variable to @templately on the show method of app/controllers/categories_controller.rb so that I could use @template to pass the id on the edit method on the template_controller.

Answer (score 0):

how about passing the params, not as an array?

```
<%= link_to image_tag("edit.png", class: "icon"), edit_category_template_path(category_id: @category.id, id: @template.id)%>
<%= link_to image_tag("bin.png", class: "icon"), category_template_path(category_id: @category.id, id: @template.id), method: :delete,
...
```

Comment: Thanks. I've tried that before and unfortunately, it does not work. I get the following error: No route matches {:action=>"edit", :category_id=>"1", :controller=>"templates", :id=>nil}, missing required keys: [:id]